# Hot to set in TWIG raw variable to another variable

Tags: symfony, variables, twig

How I can put stylize code into variable in twig?

```
{% set bold = '<strong>hello</strong>' %}
{{ bold|raw }}   {# bold text here #}

{% set eml =  bold|raw %}
{{ eml }}  {# not bold, just markup #}
```

Thx!

Comment: maybe just `{{ bold }}`?

Comment: Не работает :( отбрасывется форматирование

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the `eml` value instead of `bold`, which is already escaped, then apply the escape filter `e`.

```
{{ eml|e }}
```

Comment: text is still plain, bold